# How to set Java app to act as an Identity Provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, opensaml

I have one java app in which the user logs in. In one functionality of the app, when the user clicks on one button , it will redirect to client website where user has to login in that website. If i want to do the SSO to redirect to the client website without logging in , How can i do that? I don't want to use third party IDP'S(okta, Salesforce, azure) since the user is logging into the java app, so the user is verified, is there anyway i can make the java app as an idp and do the sso by sending saml assertion directly to the client site from the java app ?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some, to show the community your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by adding a Java [SAML client](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) to your application.

A number of these can act as an IDP as well as a SP (the application).

But this is not recommended since it does not scale.

Rather use an IDP. You get SSO so the user only has to login once.